# ¿Como puedo quitar Código de MFA de AWS?

Tags: aws

Estoy aprendiendo AWS entonces un tema que estaba viendo es MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication)
Estoy utilizando la APP Authy, me sincronice correctamente pero no puedo abrir la sesión, me da error:

Error de autenticación.
Los datos de autenticación introducidos son incorrectos. Inténtelo de nuevo.

al igual si utilizo las opciones de sincronizar y utilizar otros factores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El MFA esta ligado a un usuario en el IAM, ve al IAM, ingresa al usuario y en el tab de security credentials vas a ver los MFA devices configurados, solo es seleccionarlo y darle en "Remove"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]